# Embedded audio wont play in UIWebView on iPad but plays well in iPhone, objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uiwebview

I am downloading webpage and storing it through may app; so that I can access it offline through my app. I am loading that webpage (.html) in UIWebView. I am playing audio or video on click. If that webpage contains video then it plays fine on all devices (iPhones, and iPads). But when I access a webpage which has audio in it; then that audio is played successfully on iPhone; but on iPad (on device and simulator as well) it does not play audio file in UIWebView. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Vicky_Vignesh your answer was partially right (Anyways thanks for providing foundation). You need to provide device type and OS version with UserAgent string. I have done this way:

```objective-c
    NSString *userAgentString = @"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14E304 Safari/602.1";
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:userAgentString,@"UserAgent", nil];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSString *userAgentString = @"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36";
    NSDictionary *dictionnary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:userAgentString,@"UserAgent", nil];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionnary];
```

Add This Code While you load request to your web view..
It will be better if you add your code.

Update:

Try the below code:

webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

Add this !
If ur web view frame is whole screen.
Then Try the below code:

webView.frame=self.view.bounds;

Comment: Now audio is working fine; but webview layout is disturbed. Content is shown in only a small window and some content is missing.

Comment: @AshishBadak Pls Respond for the answer and I think Audio player is Now Playing and this answer was very helpful for you, so that update the answer as Accepted pls.

Comment: I have set scalePagesToFit property and for webView I have set proper constraints. But still webView is shrinking.